# Django filtering large dataset taking too long

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I know there have been a lot of questions regarding this subject, but I couldn't find any of my case. My problem is rather simple.

In my `influencer` app, I have `Note` model which contains about 30 fields:

```
class Note(models.Model):
    desc = models.TextField()
    likeCount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    commentCount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    postTs = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

And there is more than **1 million** `Note`s in my `PostgreSQL` database hosted by AWS RDS.

Now when I execute the following code:

```
notes = (
    Note.objects.filter(desc__icontains='some word')
                .values("likeCount", "collectCount", "shareCount", "commentCount", "postTs")[:10]
)
print(len(notes))  # Output: 10
```

it takes around **7 seconds**.

The resulting SQL query is:

```
SELECT "influencer_note"."likeCount",
       "influencer_note"."collectCount",
       "influencer_note"."shareCount",
       "influencer_note"."commentCount",
       "influencer_note"."postTs"
  FROM "influencer_note"
 WHERE UPPER("influencer_note"."desc"::text) LIKE UPPER('%some word%')
 LIMIT 10
```

I think I have done pretty much everything to optimize the query (such as selecting the only necessary fields and limiting the number of data -- *10 is obviously a small number*), but it's still taking abnormal amount of time.

What are the possible causes for this problem and how can I further optimize this?

Ultimately, I need to make a chart with the filtered queryset, which is why I need a solution other than pagination or `LIMIT`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you created `index` on that column, it is not supposed to be that slow..

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely that `icontains` (LIKE UPPER) here is an expensive operation that is taking most of query evaluation time.
Not sure if you can do much more optimizations with Django ORM, but probably you can try some of the approaches of [full text search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/search/) with using PostgreSQL vector search.

Another option is to use more suitable tool like ElasticSearch. You can read some entrance guide [here](https://sunscrapers.com/blog/how-to-use-elasticsearch-with-django/).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I'm afraid `icontains` is not the only one that is taking much time. Using `contains` on a much smaller `CharField` takes similar amount of time. I'll look into your other suggestions and let you know what worked out for me.

Comment: Even `Note.objects.all().count()` is taking roughly 150 seconds. Is this expected?

Comment: @shinhong yes, that's expected because under the hood Django will run simple query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name` doing a [full table scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_table_scan). In both scenarios for (i)contains your query will compare all your table row by row to compare `desc` with your value and that is slow.

Answer (score 1):

The query you show could be accelerated by the index:

```
create extension pg_trgm;
create index on influencer_note using gin (UPPER("desc"::text) gin_trgm_ops)
```

Although why Django injects the UPPER calls in the query here, rather than just doing the sensible thing of using ILIKE, is a mystery to me.

Comment: Unfortunately my `desc` field contains too much bytes that it throws 'index row requires 8592 bytes, maximum size is 8191' error.

Comment: That is not an error which gin_trgm_ops indexes would throw.

Comment: You were right. I missed that `gin_trgm` part. From what I understand, in order to use GIN index the column must be a tsvector. But does `tsvector` support non-English characters like Chinese? When creating triggers it seems that I need to supply the language config such as `pg_catalog.english`, but I want it to be able to search through not only English but also Chinese (or unicode). What is my option? Please excuse me if this question doesn't make sense. I'm new to SQL.

Comment: It's been more than 24 hours since I executed the command you posted. It's still running and I want to know how long I have to wait. My DB instance has the cheapest configuration: t2.micro, 1 vCPU, 1GB of RAM. Could you suggest any rough estimation of how long this thing will continue?